# Different image for each round of for loop

Tags: android, for-loop, filenames, drawable, android-drawable

I have images as resources and the filenames are image1, image2,... and so on. I'd like to use these images in a carousel. I can generate the same image in the carousel, but the name of the resource should change in every round of loop.

Here is the code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setId(i);
        imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.image_01));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        mainHorizLinLayout.addView(imageView);
    }
```

So instead of *image_01* I'd want to use *image_ + i*. I tried to create a string and use that in *R.drawable.image_01* but it did not work.

Any ideas, tanks?

Comment: `R.drawable.image_01` is a substitute for an ID. What you could do is to gather all the image ids and throw them into an array.

Comment: Suppose R.drawable.image_01 == 1111, are you guaranteed that R.drawable.image_02 is 1112?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R.drawable.image_01` is not a string (<kbd>ALT</kbd> + click to view `R` class). But these ints are in order so you can do:

```
 imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), R.drawable.image_01 + i));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
int[] images = {R.drawable.image_01, R.drawable.image_02, R.drawable.image_03, R.drawable.image_04, R.drawable.image_05};

for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setId(i);
    imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), images[i]));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    mainHorizLinLayout.addView(imageView);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way suggested before me is to have an array with the image resources ids.

Another way is to get the desired image's resource id like this:

```
int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("image_" + i, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
```